# pdf with double dot is not opened on href property html

Tags: html, pdf, browser, knockout.js, download

I have a file in my server with file name "Acuna,_Toribio_L..pdf" but when i click on the the hyperlink it throws an runtime exception.

My URL is "http://someserver.com/files/uploads/ClientApplications/Acuna,_Toribio_L..pdf"

My htmml code is

```
<ul class="attachmentFiles" data-bind='template: { foreach: HRBC.controllers.clientApplications.list.data }' id="clientApplicationsGrid">
        <li  data-bind="attr: { id: 'listItem' + Id() }">
            <a target="_blank" data-bind="attr: { href: applicationPath}">
```

Comment: What is this `data-bind` stuff doing? It looks like some more info is needed here on how that is hooked up.

Comment: @Chris this is just binding the id of each item. but this works perfect with single dot.

Comment: Is it reproducible with just plain HTML (and no binding)? Does it happen in Chrome/Firefox/IE/all?

Comment: If you type in the same url `"http://someserver.com/files/uploads/ClientApplications/Acuna,_Toribio_L..pdf"` directly to the browser can you download the file?

Comment: @nemesv this url call the function which is in my cs file. but when file with "..pdf" format it returns the error page instead of call the function.

Comment: Then the problem is in your SERVER side code it has nothing to do to your html...